# How to log the time taken by methods in Springframework?

Tags: java, spring, logging, log4j

Is it possible in springframework to log the time taken by methods [ selective | all ] automatically. By automatically i mean, i don't want to go to each method and write the log.debug ( "...." ); stuff.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

AOP is what you need here. AOP allows you to add code to your application without modifying the original code. Spring AOP prefers to accomplish this with *Proxy* objects. *Proxy* objects use a Decorator Pattern to wrap the original *Target* object and add code. The *Proxy* is configured to implement one or more interfaces of the original *Target* object.

Here, to time an application, the idea is to use the [`PerformanceMonitorInterceptor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/aop/interceptor/PerformanceMonitorInterceptor.html), one of the performance monitoring classes that ship with the Spring Framework.

The first option is to use the Spring class `ProxyFactoryBean` to create Spring AOP *Proxy* objects. To do this:

- Define your *original bean*:
- Define a `PerformanceMonitorInterceptor`:
- Define a `RegexpMethodPointcutAdvisor`:
- Define a `ProxyFactoryBean` to proxy your original bean and apply your *Advisor*
- Set the Log level for the `PerformanceMonitorInterceptor` to **TRACE**

Below a Spring configuration that illustrates these steps:

```
<beans>
  <bean id="MyServiceTarget" class="org.myapp.services.MyService">
    <property ... />
  </bean>

  <bean id="timingLogger" class="org.springframework.aop.interceptor.PerformanceMonitorInterceptor"/>

  <bean id="timingAdvisor" class="org.springframework.aop.support.RegexpMethodPointcutAdvisor">
    <property name="advice" ref="timingLogger"/>
    <property name="patterns">
      <list>
        <value>.*</value>
      </list>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <bean id="MyService" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="proxyInterfaces">
      <value>org.myapp.services.MyService</value>
    </property>
    <property name="target"><ref local="MyServiceTarget"/></property>
    <property name="interceptorNames">
      <list>
        <value>timingAdvisor</value>
      </list>
    </property>
  </bean>
</beans>
```

And the configuration of the Log level for the `PerformanceMonitorInterceptor`:

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework.aop.interceptor.PerformanceMonitorInterceptor=TRACE
```

Starting with Spring 2.0, there is another option: using [Spring 2.0 XML Schema-based configuration](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/xsd-config.html) and Spring's [AspectJ style pointcut expressions](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/aop.html#aop-pointcuts-examples). With the `ProxyFactoryBean` you have to explicitly declare the interfaces you want to proxy; using the `<aop:config>` and `<aop:advisor>` tags, you can automatically proxy every interface of every object in the bean container.

```
<beans "add xsd declarations here" >
  <bean id="MyService" class="org.myapp.services.MyService">
    <property ... />
  </bean>

  <bean id="timingAdvice"
class="org.springframework.aop.interceptor.PerformanceMonitorInterceptor"/>

  <aop:config>
    <aop:advisor pointcut="execution(* org.myapp.services.MyService.*(..))"
      advice-ref="timingAdvice"/>
  </aop:config>
</beans>
```

Comment: I don't know why but it is not working.Also edit you code from *<property name="advice" ref="timingLogger">* to *<property name="advice" ref="timingLogger"/>*

Comment: just it is not logging anything, i added the line u specified to enable the TRACE, that thing didn't worked out. Then i deleted my existing log4j prop and created a new one with everthing you mentiond, even then i am not getting anything in log. :|

Comment: That configuration snippet on its own will not do anything. You need to declare a Spring AOP BeanPostProcessor (or is it a BeanFactoryPostProcessor) to auto-proxy the beans with the timingAdvisor.

Comment: I've updated my answer to detail how to proxy Spring beans with the `ProxyFactoryBean`

Answer (score 4):

You can take a look at [stagemonitor](http://www.stagemonitor.org/). It is a open source java web application performance monitor. It captures response time metrics, JVM metrics, request details (including a call stack captured by the request profiler) and more. The overhead is very low.

Optionally, you can use the great timeseries database graphite with it to store a long history of datapoints that you can look at with fancy dashboards.

Example Screenshot:
[image]

Take a look at the [project website](http://www.stagemonitor.org/) to see more screenshots, feature descriptions and documentation.

Note: I am the developer of stagemonitor

Answer (score 2):

Finally i figured out how to do this.

First of all see the post by '*Pascal Thivent*', it did a great help to me. After changing your log4j.properties and creating the **timingAdvisor** what you have to is, binding this adviser to the class you wan to enable the debugging. You have to change your code like this.

**earlier code:**

```
<bean id="myTableDao" class="com.xyz.sc.db.dao.MyTableDaoImpl" parent="commonDataSource" >                  
            <property name="anotherDao" ref="anotherDao"/>
    </bean>
```

**New code.**

```
<bean id="myTableDaoTarget" class="com.xyz.sc.db.dao.MyTableDaoImpl" parent="commonDataSource" >                
        <property name="anotherDao" ref="anotherDao"/>
</bean>


    <bean id="myTableDao" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="proxyInterfaces">
        <value>com.xyz.sc.db.dao.MyTableDao</value>
    </property>
    <property name="target"><ref local="myTableDaoTarget"/></property>
    <property name="interceptorNames">
        <list>
            <value>timingAdvisor</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) for this, declare a log pointcut called by wildcard with pre- and post handling by before() and after() advice.

Answer (score 1):

I see that there has already been an accepted answer here, but I'd encourage everyone to take a look at the latest release of Spring Toolsuite (SpringSource's distro of Eclipse). It comes with a profiling utility out of the box, Spring Insight, that provides these exact statistics at runtime in a nice format. Just deploy your app to its internal tomcat, hit a few pages, then go to the /insight servlet and see the time taken in each method called all the way down to the SQL statements that were executed and how long they took.

Here's a link to a nice writeup about Spring Insight that should get you what you want in just a few minutes. http://www.dotkam.com/2009/10/28/spring-insight-in-action-5-minutes-from-scratch/